# 'Io facebucco', 'Tu facebucchi', 'Egli facebucca', and so on

Tags: verbs, foreign-words, borrowing

In un articolo di Michele Serra, noto per la rubrica 'L'Amaca', leggo:

> ... se non *twitto* e non *facebucco* è perché mi pare di disturbare ...

Credo che 'io twitto, tu twitti, ...' sia ormai completamente accettabile, ma non avevo mai sentito 'io facebucco, tu facebucchi, ...'.

Allora, cosa ne pensate di questa frase: 'Se facebuccassimo potremmo conoscerci meglio'?

Comment: Nice question :-) Actually I would say "io feisbucco", "tu feisbucchi", etc. In fact that's the way you would pronounce it - and I hope we agree that "io facebooko" or "io facebookko" would be bad transcriptions into Italian of the original sound. So if you can't use the original root, "facebook", a better transcription could be "feisbuccare".

Comment: "Credo che 'io twitto, tu twitti, ...' sia ormai completamente accettabile" except that *I* 'd spit in your eye if you used these terms in front of me. Said in a less colourful way: that verb is quite questionable. In my opinion you should still say *io pubblico un tweet*.

Comment: @Bakuriu: It's all a question of registers. I might use the word “twittare” when speaking with a friend or in an informal email exchange, and “pubblicare un tweet” in a more formal context, don't you think?

Comment: @DaG, yes; however in a very formal context you could say '*cinguettare*', though. I.e., 'se *cinguettaste* meno, sareste ancor più felici', 'in taluni casi è inevitabile pubblicare un cinguettio' and so on.

Comment: "facebucco" — it sounds horrible. It would be ground for leaving a significant other using it.

Answer (score 5):

Penso che al di fuori dei lettori abituali di Michele Serra nessuno capirebbe! 
Credo che questo sia un neologismo del giornalista limitato al suo articolo.

Concordo che twittare sia abbastanza usato, ma d'altra parte potrebbe essere un calco dall'inglese "to tweet" (http://mashable.com/2009/06/11/twitter-ap-stylebook/). 
"To facebook", invece, non esiste neppure in inglese, mentre l'azione di scrivere è "to post" (già italianizzata in "postare").

La frase di esempio potrebbe essere resa con "se ci aggiungessimo tutti su facebook potremmo conoscerci meglio" o qualcosa di simile.

Comment: It seems that in English they are [confused](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/is-facebook-as-a-verb-different-from-google-or-photoshop) about what specifically the verb "to facebook" might actually mean (except, of course, "to communicate on Facebook").

Comment: Oh I see, you are right. Anyway from my limited experience (I'm not native English speaker, and I speak English mostly with non-native speakers, but I read English articles and blogs) I've never heard of "to facebook", while "to tweet" is much more common.

Comment: Twittare (che ormai non scriverei neanche più in corsivo) è la cosa che si fa su Twitter, equivalente all'inglese _to tweet_, anche se più razionalmente molti dicono semmai _cinguettare_. _Twitterare_ non esiste e direi che non dovrebbe esistere. Similmente, quel che si fa su Facebook non è _facebookare_ o _feisbuccare_ o l'ibrido _facebuccare_, ma, volendo usare un anglicismo, _postare_. Serra voleva usare una parola buffa e fulminea (e l'ha messa in corsivo), non intendeva coniare un neologismo duraturo.

Comment: Io non ho letto il corsivo di Serra citato nella domanda, ma siamo proprio sicuri che intendesse “postare”? Da quel frammento sembrerebbe che intendesse qualcosa di più generale, come “usare/frequentare Facebook”.

Comment: "...se non twitto e non facebucco è perché mi pare di disturbare già fin troppo qui così, in questa forma quotidiana e quadratina" (si trova online anche il testo completo). Io la intendo prevalentemente come postare, o al limite anche ribattere ai commenti

Answer (score 5):

Trovo che sia un'“invenzione” normalissima, soprattutto nel linguaggio giornalistico, pubblicitario e in genere creativo, ma non solo. Anche se non quanto l'inglese (che può prendere virtualmente ogni sostantivo e usarlo come verbo), anche l'italiano è molto fertile da questo punto di vista: se domani qualcuno dice “pizziamo o cinemiamo?”, “non star sempre ad aifonare”, etc., la cosa può parere più o meno gradevole esteticamente, ma è perfettamente comprensibile.

Piuttosto, è interessante notare che questa fertilità è limitata alla prima coniugazione, mentre non esistono neologismi verbali recenti di altre coniugazioni.

Comment: Questo è vero e interessante. Da notare anche che spesso si prende un verbo inglese e lo si "fa diventare" italiano, in prima coniugazione: googlare, matchare, linkare, chattare, cliccare...tutti esempi dove il corrispondente italiano non esisteva e ce lo si è inventato così.

Comment: credo siano secoli che non si crei più un verbo non della prima coniugazione. Forse c'è qualcosa in -ire, ma a me non viene in mente nulla.

Comment: Cerchiamo di imporci noi! Googlire, chàttere. Scherzi a parte, forse è una domanda interessante da porre: qual è il più recente verbo italiano non della prima? Sarebbe un attimo rispondere se si avesse un dizionario con gli anni di prima attestazione delle parole (come lo Zingarelli), in un formato comodo per farci ricerche.

Answer (score 4):

A parte che io non userei mai quel verbo e comunque preferirei la forma "io feisbucco, tu feisbucchi", credo che in un contesto non formale l'espressione "aggiorno il mio stato su Facebook" sia troppo pesante, e inventarsi un verbo può essere utile.