# Most recent non-first conjugation Italian verb

Tags: verbs, history

Within the context of [another question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/io-facebucco-tu-facebucchi-egli-facebucca-and-so-on) an interesting question has emerged: which is the most recent Italian verb that doesn't belong to the first conjugation (i.e., not ending in *-are*)? In fact, all recent neologisms are in *-are*: *formattare*, *masterizzare*, but also, say, *allunare* (1961) or *ammarare* (1918).

(It would be probably easy to find the answer if a vocabulary giving the earliest occurrence of each word were available in a format suitable to do custom searches.)

Comment: Corpora are available, this one for instance: http://corpora.dslo.unibo.it/coris_eng.html

Comment: @martina: Yes, lot of them, but they are often either strictly bounded temporally (for instance, the one you point out collects mostly 1980s and 1990s texts, while for this question I believe we have to look farther back in time) or unwieldy to look up (especially since here we are not looking for a specific word or form). Thank for the useful link, anyway!

Comment: Well, you're right, and I don't know any other corpora which dates back in time. Actually your question is very interesting, but don't you think that it all refers to Latin? That is, that verbs mostly reflect the original Latin conjugation?

Comment: DaG, forse *bannire*; per esempio, 'mi ha *bannito* l'accesso al sito', oppure 'sono stato *bannito*'. So che *bannare* potrebbe essere un'alternativa, ma mi sembra strano dire 'sono stato *bannato*', forse perché influenzato dalla parola 'zittito'.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: Grazie dello spunto. Io personalmente ho sempre sentito e letto “bannare”; “bannire” è una tua proposta oppure è attestato in fonti “pubbliche” di qualche tipo?

Comment: DaG, ora non ho accesso a Google Books, e non posso dire se esistono fonti o se la parola sia in uso, ma certamente domani accerterò, anche se, per adesso, è solo una mia preferenza.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Bannire? No grazie. Ho giocato abbastanza con vari videogiochi anni fa e ho *sempre* e *solo* sentito usare la parola "bannare" (compreso "bannato"). Stessa cosa anche in riferimento a utenti di forum o altri siti web.

Comment: "*Bannire*" is [correct](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bandire/) - actually more correct (and ancient) than "*bannare*", although the meanings are not necessarily entirely equivalent. In fact it is not a neologism but the archaic form of "*bandire*" :-)

Comment: @DaG Ma ti riferisci solo a verbi ottenuti come calco/prestito da altre lingue? Non è chiaro dalla domanda. Si capisce che si cerca il verbo in italiano in assoluto più recente che non è di prima coniugazione.

Comment: @martina: Sì, la mia domanda è proprio questa: quale sia il verbo più recente non della prima. Di fatto, molti ingressi recenti sono calchi/prestiti, ma non ponevo vincoli di qualche tipo.

Comment: Due verbi recenti (e non "discussi" come *scansire*) sono *usufruire* e *sfoltire*, che Google data rispettivamente al 1922 e al 1960.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure this is the most recent, however of course any answer is going to be obsolete soon, but I can think of *perplimere*, which is a "made-up" infinitive of the adjective, with past principle form, *perplesso*.

It is a made up verb, last time I looked up the Latin form *perplexus, -a, um* it did not have a corresponding verb form.

Comment: +1 You might add these links: [http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/significato-origine-perplimere](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/significato-origine-perplimere) and [http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_080.html](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_080.html)

Comment: This is about the process of [retroformazione](http://linguista.blogautore.repubblica.it/2009/07/25/quel-tale-mi-perplime/) (which has produced the verb "perplimere").

Comment: @Sklivvz: Thanks. It is indeed made up, and if anything it should rather be *perplettere* (just like *plexus* was the past participle of *plecto*: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dplecto1 ).

Comment: perplimere is more a joke than a verb

Answer (score 5):

'to scan': io utilizzo 'scansire'. lo trovo più elegante di 'scannerizzare' o del piu truce 'scannare' che comunque ogni tanto mi capita di sentire.

Comment: +1 You might add this link to your answer: [http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_093.html](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_093.html)

Comment: A me personalmente “scansire” suona alieno (io uso un più classico “scandire”, che considero l'uovo di Colombo), ma a quanto pare è usato. Grazie.

Comment: io uso "scansionare" :-)

Comment: Spesso sento "scandire"

Comment: @Sklivvz Scandire al posto di scannerizzare, quando il verbo già esiste?

Comment: non ho capito il commento di @martina. Comunque personalmente penso che _scandire_ sia la traduzione migliore. E' vero che si tratta di un caso molto controverso, comunque _to scan_ e _scandire_ hanno la stessa provenienza dal latino [_scandĕre_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scandire/)

Comment: Peraltro l'autore dell'[articolo su treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_093.html) linkato (!) da @randomatlabuser pare avere la stessa mia preferenza per _scandire_

Comment: @WalterTross Dal momento che il verbo "scandire" esiste già con un suo significato avulso da quello di "to scan", chiedevo come mai sia usato in quel senso, io non l'ho mai sentito, non lo capirei senza contesto e non credo che sia corretto trasferire la sfera semantica di un lemma esistente su un altro significato.

Comment: @martina, la sfera semantica non viene trasferita, si amplia. E' inevitabile se non si crea un lemma nuovo, ed è la stessa cosa che è successa in inglese per _to scan_!

Comment: @WalterTross Non mi è chiaro come si possa ampliare dal significato di "pronunciare le sillabe/lettere di una parola/frase in maniera separata" singolarmente a "scanerizzare un documento, cioè farne copia digitale".

Comment: @martina, può non essere chiaro, ma è certamente possibile (anche perché in ambito elettronico _scandire_ è utilizzato da prima dell'invenzione dello scanner)

Comment: Dimenticavo qualche riferimento: [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scandire/), [Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scandire.shtml), [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=scandire)

Comment: Vorrei proporre l'espressione "acquisire via (o a mezzo) scanner". Forse meno elegante ma verificata sul campo e non ha mai generato perplessità.

Comment: @martina, scusa il paternalismo ma che tu non abbia mai sentito un uso linguistico non dice niente sulla sua legittimità (soprattutto quando altre persone lo conoscono e i dizionari lo riportano). E poi – per limitarsi all'ambito informatico – a parole come ”salvare”, “compilare”, “uscire”, “finestra” e varie altre è successo lo stesso. L'originaria area semantica si è allargata fino a incorporare significati molto lontani da quelli originari. Nello specifico, il senso comune alle varie accezioni di “scandire” è “passare in rassegna sistematicamente” (un verso, uno slogan, un'immagine).